# How use marshal.Copy function to read data into memory?

Tags: c#, delphi, memory, pointers, encryption

I'm trying to port a desencrypt function i have in Delphi to C#. 
in delphi i use the function Move to get data into memory using a pointer, so i tried to use the marshal.copy function with the same results but sometimes i get an acces violation exception and sometimes blank spaces.
leave attached the code of the function.
Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

```
    public string prDecode(string s)
    {
        byte[] ArrayMap = new byte[256] {0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  
                                         0, 0, 0, 62, 0, 0, 0, 63, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59,60,
                                         61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
                                         11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
                                         36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
                                         51, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; 
        int I;
        char[] ArrayS = s.ToCharArray(0, s.Length);
        string resultado = "";
        char[] ArrayR = resultado.ToCharArray(0, resultado.Length);
        switch (s.Length)
        {
            case 2: 
                I = ArrayMap[ArrayS[0]] + (ArrayMap[ArrayS[1]] << 6);
                ArrayR = new char[1];
                Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)I, ArrayR, 0, ArrayR.Length);

                break;
            case 3:
                I = ArrayMap[ArrayS[0]] + (ArrayMap[ArrayS[1]] << 6) + 
                    (ArrayMap[ArrayS[2]] << 12);
                ArrayR = new char[2];
                Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)I, ArrayR, 0, ArrayR.Length);
                break;

            case 4:
                I = ArrayMap[ArrayS[0]] + (ArrayMap[ArrayS[1]] << 6) + 
                    (ArrayMap[ArrayS[2]] << 12) + (ArrayMap[ArrayS[3]] << 18);
                ArrayR = new char[3];
                Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)I, ArrayR, 0, ArrayR.Length);
                break;
        }
        string clave = new string (ArrayR);
        return clave;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the function you're looking for is [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft) or [Buffer.BlockCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) rather than Marshal.Copy.  Marshal.Copy is for copying data to and from unmanaged memory.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use Marshal unless you are accessing unmanaged memory for legacy code. Managed code has no need for pointers & using managed methods will be much quicker.

What you're looking for I think, is Array.Copy to copy between arrays using managed code.